# como puedo resolver este error

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

estoy haciendo una peticion http en js y html y estoy corriendo el proyecto en el servidor de xammp pero me marca error 401 y un error de cors

Adjunto codigo:

````
```<script>
  var url = "",
  credentials = btoa("");

     // (B) FETCH WITH HTTP AUTH
       fetch ("",{

method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS",
 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, 
Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization",
"Content-Type": 'application/json',
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, 
Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization",
}),
mode : "cors"

  })
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.error)
    }
    return response.json();
})

   .then((result) => {
    if (result.status != 200) { throw new Error("Bad Server Response"); }
return result.text();
 })
    .then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
 })

   .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
 </script>```
````

Quite las url que ocupo como son institucionales pero no se como habilitar el cors ya que el error que arroja es error de cors osea uso unas credenciales para hacer una validacion pero la validacion funciona pero no muestra la repsuesta del servidor porque son urls de diferentes dominos que tendria que hacer en el codigo para que funcione bien la peticion

Adjunto imageni del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El cors se habilita o no del lado del servidor, no de tu script, que actúa como cliente (haciendo peticiones a la api de tesseract). Si el cliente pudiera elegir las políticas, ¿qué sentido tendrían frente a ataques y todo eso. Por otro lado... no se ve en tu código la llamada real a la api (incluyendo método de autenticación, etc.), pero he comprobado que hay una [buena documentación](https://tesseract.mx/docs/api#Registro) explicando el proceso de acceso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que habilitar el acceso a los recursos desde el servidor

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Esto permite el acceso desde cualquier direccion. No es lo mas seguro, en vez del asterisco puedes agregar direcciones de confianza.